# Why does this pipeline get SIGTTIN?

Tags: bash, pipe, signals

When I run the command `for i in *.log; do cat "$i" | sort; done | more`, the pipeline gets a `SIGTTIN` signal and is stopped.

```
bash$ for i in *.log; do cat "$i" | sort; done | more
### (one screenful of output...)
--More--
### (press Space)
[1]+  Stopped                 for i in *.log;
do
    cat "$i" | sort;
done | more
bash$ echo $?
149     # indicates SIGTTIN(21)
```

(I substituted a simple `cat` for a more elaborate and complex `awk` script.)

I don't see why a `SIGTTIN` is generated, as no process reads from tty, except `more`, which is not in the background. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: I can not reproduce this with `GNU bash, version 4.4.5(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-openbsd6.0)`.